# How to write a file automatically after every change?

Tags: key-bindings, save

Something that helps in text editing and proofreading is that for Insert mode, I have set an IMAP:

```
:imap zz ^[:w^M
```

and when I type `zz` I return to command mode and also write the current buffer. This makes `latexmk` reprocess my `.tex`.

However, I also make smaller changes like replacing single characters with `r` or `daw` for deleting a word or pasting a register. How can I tell Vim to write the current buffer every time I do such changes?

Comment: You can set a very low `updatecount`, so that Vim will write to the swap file very often. This obviously may cause slowdowns.

Answer (score 6):

If your main motivation is updating an alternative (compiled) representation in another tool, you can use the `FocusLost` event (present in GVIM and some terminals), so updates will happen when you leave Vim (for the other tool).

```
:autocmd FocusLost * update
```

For certain filetypes / buffers, replace `*` with `<buffer>` and define in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim`.

You can add additional `:help autocmd-events`, e.g. `CursorHold,CursorHoldI,InsertLeave`. What you literally asked for is `TextChanged,TextChangedI`, but its `:help` explicitly warns:

> Careful: This is triggered very often, don't
>     do anything that the user does not expect or
>     that is slow.

Comment: `b:changedtick` could also be useful in this context: it counts "[t]he total number of changes to the current buffer [...] incremented for each change. An undo command is also a change in this case".  FWIW.

Answer (score 5):

Use event-based autocommands: I suggest `TextChanged` for normal mode, and `InsertLeave` for insert mode - which can also replace your `zz` mapping.